# javascript_include_tag behavior after remove sprocket in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsbundling-rails, cssbundling-rails

I started a fresh rails 7 application using `jsbundling-rails` (with esbuild) and `cssbundling-rails` (with bootstrap).

The pipeline works well to build assets. After testing that, I removed sprockets gem and configs from application (basically, I removed all calls with `.assets` on config files)

So, after remove sprocket, my assets can't be reach from frontend
`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

I'm debugging but it isn't clear what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

After I've seen some tutorials, I discovered which sprockets can't be removed.

While I'm upgrading I removed a lot of gems, and someone that import sprockets as a dependency.

I fixed adding sprockets directly:

```rb
gem "sprockets-rails", :require => "sprockets/railtie"
```

I also simplified my `assets.rb` file:

```rb
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = "1.0"

# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font")
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts")
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("node_modules/summernote/dist/font")
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app/assets/fonts")

# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in the app/assets
# folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )
```

It's important search for other files which use `.assets` from code.

My `manifest.js` file (sprockets looks to that file):

```js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../builds
```

#### References:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8DmZhkRoJs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhM-Wh9Pmd4